# How to help citation managers understand my document's metadata?

Tags: pdf, metadata, hyperxmp, xmp

When I am importing my PDF to Mendeley, it doesn't correctly recognise the title, author etc of my document. I suspect that it just uses criteria like the size of the font to understand what the title is.

I am producing PDF metadata with hyperref, but it doesn't look like it reads them (I can see them in the file properties though). I guess that the same problem may happen with using other software.

**Apart from the main hyperref metadata, what else should I do to properly attach metadata to my document?**

Can I somehow attach something like a "BibTeX entry" with my document?

Comment: If the document has a DOI then placing it somewhere visible may help in Mendeley: http://support.mendeley.com/customer/en/portal/articles/227883-how-does-the-automatic-document-details-extraction-work- Not sure where to put it though. Also: IMO Mendeley should implement regular pdf metadata, that cannot be very difficult...

Answer (score 1):

You should use package [`hyperxmp`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp) because `hyperref` alone does not create `XMP` metadata. For your purpose `\hypersetup{pdfdoi=10.1000/182}` might be of special interest.

You can attach your bibtex file with package [`embedfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile). I am unaware of a standadised way to include bibliographies in XMP.